# Is my laptop battery dead? Should I get a replacement, It is an HP laptop and I know the BIOS may not be up to date, would that effect the battery?

Tags: laptop, battery

Is this laptops battery dead and needing to be replaced? Or could this be a result of BIOS not being up to date?

[image]

Comment: If ur laptop can't stand for long on battery..yes replace it

Comment: It is weird that under `Energy (design)` you only have `3.0Wh`. I doubt that a laptop has such a small battery. And the `Voltage` is pretty low. I would guess something went worng on reading the battery-status chip. But I don't know what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this laptops battery dead and needing to be replaced?

I would say: yes.

> Or could this be a result of BIOS not being up to date?

Unlikely. The BIOS itself has not a lot to do with the battery. The battery is charged from the power supply, it is discharged through supplying electricity to the system. It basically is a chemical process.

I have yet to see one that shows "3.0Wh" under "Energy (design)" and "0.00%" under "Percentage". I would expect "Capacity" to go down (one of my notebooks has that on "33.2%" but it never leaves the charger :D).  If anything *is* wrong it could be wrongly read data from the battery but that is proven by the time you have on your battery when it is charged as full. If that is under 60 minutes ... get a new one. If it is 2 hour-ish I would say a problem with reading the data.

I would put the battery in the refrigerator (in a sealed bag) (yes, I am serious) for a bit.